# Bayesian Regression and Classification paper by Bishop and Tipping

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking at this paper by [Bishop and Tipping](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bishop-nato-bayes.pdf)

And I do not understand how they derive an equation in (8), which is:

$$p(t| \mathbb{x}, \mathbb{w}, \sigma^2) = \left( \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2} \right)^{1/2} \exp \Bigg\{ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}|y(\mathbb{x},\mathbb{w})-t^2| \Bigg\}$$

and equation (1) is:
$$t_n = y(\mathbb{x_n},\mathbb{w})+\epsilon_n$$
and equation (7):
$$p(\epsilon|\sigma^2) = \mathcal{N}(\epsilon|0,\sigma^2)= \left( \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2} \right)^{1/2} \exp \Bigg\{ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \epsilon^2 \Bigg\}$$

I can see this is trivial, but I cannot jut see how they arrive at (8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $C$ is a real constant and that $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. It is a property of the normal distribution that $C + Z \sim \mathcal{N}(C, \sigma^2)$. In particular, $C$ gets added to the mean (which was zero) and the variance remains the same.

Now, $ y(\mathbf x_n, \mathbf w)$ is a deterministic function of weights $\mathbf w$ and data $\mathbf x$; $\varepsilon_n$ is a normal random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Therefore, $t_n$ is a normal random variable with mean $y(\mathbf x_n, \mathbf w)$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The distribution of $t_n$ is therefore given by Equation (8).